# Eclipse pre-commit hook to execute arbitrary logic

Tags: eclipse, svn, pre-commit-hook

Does eclipse support pre-commit checks for executing logic in a script or java class? Specifically, I need logic to search the source file for `println`, `TODO`, etc., statements before committing to SVN.

If you program, you know what I'm talking about... :-)

```
public void submitOrder(Order order){
    if(order.valid()){
       println("hi!")
       orderProcessor.validatePayment(order)
       println("hi2")
       ...
    }else{
       println("logging to journal...")   //TODO remove this later
       journal.log(INVALID_ORDER, order)
       println("after journal")

       println("really throwing exception now!")
       throw new InvalidOrderException(order)
    }
}
```